# PayPal In-App Purchase for Android OS - Server/Client Model

Tags: iphone, android, in-app-purchase, paypal

We are writing an application for Android OS which communicates with a server to perform its operations.

This application is subscription based and it's the responsibility of server to let the device know about subscription status of currently logged-in user.

We are planning to write In-App purchase using PayPal services, Therefore,I just need to know, Does PayPal Supports Server/Client Model, like iOS Does?

**The following is the detailed process we are following for iPhone Applications.**

1. Device Sends purchase request to Apple's payment gateway
2. The payment gateway sends back a digitally signed receipt.
3. The device forwards this receipt to our application server
4. The application server sends the receipt (for verification) to Apple's public Web API
5. Apple's Web API Verifies the validity of receipt and returns readable contents of receipt back to app server.
6. The server adjusts the subscription of paid user and sends "Success" back to the device.

Comment: Hey there! Generally, we don't add greetings or "thanks" to questions on StackOverflow. Also, you should consider selecting more answers where appropriate. People will be more motivated to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google launched In-app billing yesterday.
It uses the Android Market for payment.

A detailed documentation/examples can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html).

Comment: Thanks, We already have moved to google in-App and left PayPal.

Comment: Yeah Paypal API sucked! Moved my projects over as well. Here's another InApp Purchase tut: http://www.anddev.org/post96123.html

Comment: Question -- if you are using Paypal for your subscription model, are you selling on the Android market without violating the TOS? In your subscription model, does the user get charged every month with or without a prompt?